# Removing/forgetting widgets on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to the Tkinter module (and quite new to python) I can't for the life of me figure out how to use the remove or forget methods to hide widgets in a grid. I can't seem to find relevant examples online and the tutorial documents have given me everything but the syntax. Below is the code I've been using to try and figure it out. Apologies if this overly trivial...

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


def delete():
    #where I would like to delete the label 'label'

window = Tk()
window.title("Window")
window.configure(background='#e4e5ff')

label = ttk.Label(window, text='text').grid(column=1, row=0)

ttk.Button(window, text='text',command = delete).grid(column=2,row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried typing in the exact title of this question into the stackoverflow search box? That returns a lot of things, some of which have examples.

Comment: See [`grid_forget`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_forget-method).

Answer (score 0):

To do that you will have to use 2 lines to define and layout the widget (which is good practice anyway).

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def delete():
    label.grid_forget()

window = Tk()
window.title("Window")
window.configure(background='#e4e5ff')

label = ttk.Label(window, text='text')
label.grid(column=1, row=0)

btn = ttk.Button(window, text='text',command = delete)
btn.grid(column=2,row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

However, I suspect this is an XY problem. Are you trying to delete it in order to replace it with another Label? If so, you need to update the current label, not delete it and replace it.

```
def delete():
    label.config(text='new_text')
```

Comment: Your code is a bit unclear. Your function is called `delete` but it doesn't actually delete anything, it just removes it from view.

Comment: Ok, great that was it. Thanks for your help.